# Can an object subscribe to its own notifications?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, uitextfield, nsnotifications, uitextfielddelegate

For example, [a `UITextField` cannot be its own delegate](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13469-subclassing-uitextfield-delegate.html), but is it OK to just have it register itself as an observer of its own notifications? Looks weird but seems to work fine. Thoughts?

```
// MyTextField.h

@interface MyTextField : UITextField
@end

// MyTextField.m

@interface MyTextField ()
- (void)myTextFieldDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification;
@end

@implementation MyTextField

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(myTextFieldDidChange:)
         name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
         object:self];
    }
}

- (void)myTextFieldDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Do custom stuff here.
}

@end
```

Comment: You are turning a view into a controller, but if it works it works.  For better MVC, have the ViewController that contains the textfield be the delegate.

Comment: But, the method above keeps the view controller cleaner and allows the `MyTextField` to be reused in other view controllers without them having to re-implement the `textFieldDidChange:` functionality in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing seems fine, but there's a purer solution for this particular example:

```
// MyTextField.h

@interface MyTextField : UITextField
@end

// MyTextField.m

@interface MyTextField ()
- (void)myTextFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField;
@end

@implementation MyTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(myTextFieldDidChange:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)myTextFieldDidChange:(MyTextField *)myTextField {
    // Do custom stuff here.
}

@end
```

Check out the [`UIControlEvents` reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents).